# Yii2 validation rule for array

Tags: php, yii2

I've an attribute in model which I want to validate in such a way that - It must be an array and must have 3 element, also every element inside array must be a string. Currently I'm using.

```
['config', 'each', 'rule' => ['string']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a custom validator, e.g. :

```
['config', function ($attribute, $params) {
    if(!is_array($this->$attribute) || count($this->$attribute)!==3){
         $this->addError($attribute, 'Error message');
    }
}],
['config', 'each', 'rule' => ['string']]
```

Read more about [creating validators](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#creating-validators).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a  `custom` `validation` rules like below:

```
public function rules()
{
    return  ['config','checkIsArray'];
}

public function checkIsArray($attribute, $params)
{
    if (empty($this->config)) {
        $this->addError('config', "config cannot be empty");
    }
    elseif (!is_array($this->config)) {
        $this->addError('config', "config must be array.");
    }
    elseif (count($this->config)<3) {
        $this->addError('config', "config must have 3 elements");
    }
    else {
        foreach ($this->config as $value) {
            if (!is_string($value)) {
                $this->addError('config ', "config should have only string values.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```